# wtforms/flask_wtf validator: FileAllowed, not catching forbidden file extensions

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

### Observed Issue

I am trying to validate file extensions on a FileField field. The form successfully validates even when I pass files with extensions not included in the validator constructor. In this example I am using a test `.pdf` file which is not blank:

`validators=[FileRequired(),FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'], 'Images only!')]`

form contents:
data = `<FileStorage: 'test.pdf' ('application/pdf')>`
errors = `()`

### Code

#### route

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from forms import ConsoleUploadForm

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'superdupersecret'

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = ConsoleUploadForm()  

    if form.validate_on_submit:
        # this is just my debug statement
        print(f"validated with -> {form.console_log_file.data} {form.console_log_file.errors}")

    return render_template("home.html", form=form)
```

#### form class

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed, FileRequired

class ConsoleUploadForm(FlaskForm):
    console_log_file = FileField("Choose File...", render_kw={"class": "custom-file-input"}, validators=[
        FileRequired(), FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'], 'Images only!')])
```

#### HTML

```
<html>
    <form method="POST" action="/home" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <legend>Log Selection:</legend>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="console_log_file">Console Log File</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        {{ form.console_log_file(class="custom-file-input") }}
                        {{ form.console_log_file.label(class="custom-file-label") }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            {% if form.console_log_file.errors %}
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {% for error in form.console_log_file.errors %}
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {% endif %}

        </div>
    </form>
</html>
```

### Desired Outcome

On pressing submit having passed a forbidden file extension type to the FileField I would expect to see elements in `forms.console_log_file.errors` and see them in my debug print statement.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of the handwritten typo... left out the parenthesis when trying to call the validate_on_submit method.

### route

`if form.validate_on_submit:`   ---becomes--->   `if form.validate_on_submit():`